# Least mean square optimization with a constraint in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, least-squares

I have a piece of code in matlab:

```
deg = 0:57;

theta = deg*pi/180;

N = 16;
lambda = 0.1;

dxy = 0.4*lambda;
nn = 1:N;
y = (nn - 0.5*(N+1))*dxy;

BB = [0.00 0.00 0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    0.63    0.57    0.29    0.23    0.20    0.17    0.15    0.14    0.12    0.11    0.10    0.10    0.09    0.09    0.08    0.08    0.07    0.07    0.07    0.06    0.06    0.06    0.06    0.00    0.00    0.00];

AA = exp(2*pi*1j/lambda*sin(theta')*y);

w = AA \ fliplr(BB)';
```

I want a least mean square solution to w for AA*w = BB' such that 
the absolute values of elements of **w** equal to 1.

Comment: You mean you want to normalize each element of w such that the absolute value `|w(i)|=1` for each element i?

Comment: @TryHard. Yes. Exactly.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I misconstrued your question. Have you looked at this: http://se.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html ?